# Symfony2 form collection not allowing additional entities to be set on update

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

We have followed the example provided by [AcmePizzaBundle](https://github.com/beberlei/AcmePizzaBundle/).
We have a `DeliveryType` form which holds a date field and a `deliveryItems` collection as it follows:

```
$builder
    ->add('date', 'date', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'datepicker' => true
    ))
    ->add('deliveryItems', 'collection', array(
        'type'         => new DeliveryItemType(),
        'allow_add'    => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'prototype'    => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
    ))
;
```

The `Delivery` entity holds a relation with the `DeliveryItem` entity:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DeliveryItem", mappedBy="delivery", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $deliveryItems;
```

When we create a Delivery, with 4 related DeliveryItems everything appears to work. This works due to the following code in the createAction:

```
...

if ($form->isValid()) {

    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

...
```

If we then go to edit this delivery, we have an issue in which if we add an additional DeliveryItem (total of 5 now), then one gets striped out. This is our controller for the updateAction:

```
/**
 * Edits an existing Delivery entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="delivery_update")
 * @Method("PUT")
 * @Template("AcmeAppBundle:Delivery:edit.html.twig")
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('AcmeAppBundle:Delivery')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {

        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('delivery'));
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    $editForm = $this->createForm(new DeliveryType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('delivery_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));
    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {

        $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction(); // transaction

        try {

            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
            $em->getConnection()->commit(); // transaction

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('delivery_show', array('id' => $id)));

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            $em->getConnection()->rollback(); // transaction

            $entity = new Delivery();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('delivery'));

        }

    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

Interestingly, if we do `print_r($request)` it seems like only the first item is kept, and then all the other fields will eventually get updated the more items we add in (in this example we had 4 and we add a 5th, which overrides the second field):

```
[request] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object
        (
            [parameters:protected] => Array
                (
                    [_method] => PUT
                    [northerncam_appbundle_delivery] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2014-08-07
                            [poNumber] => 345
                            [deliveryItems] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [stock] => 1
                                            [quantity] => 1
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [stock] => 1
                                            [quantity] => 5
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [stock] => 1
                                            [quantity] => 3
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [stock] => 1
                                            [quantity] => 4
                                        )

                                )

                            [submit] => 
                            [_token] => QpaKjcOP35kDBC1EAW8dDGpugtoxF4-MhL5rC6pYTVU
                        )

                )

        )
```

Even more weird, if we add an additional 5 elements to the original Delivery (with 4), we end up with overriding three of the original fields, and then the 5th item is created additionally. So we end up with something like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [stock] => 1
        [quantity] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [stock] => 1
        [quantity] => 5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [stock] => 1
        [quantity] => 6
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [stock] => 1
        [quantity] => 7
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [stock] => 1
        [quantity] => 8
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [stock] => 1
        [quantity] => 9
    )
```

We're on Symfony v2.5.2 and doctrine/orm v2.4.4

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Our code works just perfectly. The issue was with the live form generation handled by [phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle) (v3.0.0-beta 3) as pointed out in the [Issue #738](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/issues/738).

We thus replaced line 108 with `options.initial_size = $this.parents(collection_id).find('.collection-items').children().length;` as commented by @wolfwolker and the nrun `php app/console assetic:dump` and now everything works.